# How can I get td values using dom and php

Tags: php, dom

I have a table such this :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Values</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>6000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And I want to get td's content. But I could not manage it.

```
<?PHP
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("figures.html"); 
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tds=$table->getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach ($tds as $t){
   echo $t->nodeValue, "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` always returns a `DOMNodeList` so you have to do `$tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('td')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this code:

1. To load from an HTML file, you need to use `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`, not `loadHTML()` as you have done. Use `$dom->loadHTMLFile("figures.html")`.
2. You can't use `getElementsByTagName()` on a `DOMNodeList` as you have done (on `$table`). It can only be used on a `DOMDocument`.

You could do something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("figures.html");
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

// Find the correct <table> element you want, and store it in $table
// ...

// Assume you want the first table
$table = $tables->item(0);

foreach ($table->childNodes as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {
    echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just directly search for all elements with tag name `td` (though I'm sure you want to do that in a table-specific manner.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop to display the multiple `td's` with `id` attributes in it such that each `td` must signify a different `id` in html file

for example

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
echo "<td id ='id_".$i."'>".$tdvalue."</td>";
}
```

and then again you can fetch the `td` values by just iterating another for loop over `getElementById`

Comment: <table> has id, but no ids for <td>s. Anyway, I should use tags instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

The **td** data can be found inside **childNodes**

```
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML("your-url");
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows = $tables->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->childNodes[0]->nodeValue;
    }
```