# How to insert extracted data between td tags into database?

Tags: database, insert

I am trying to insert extracted data between td tags into database(student_information), however I always got no data in the database. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
$matchcount = preg_match_all('/<div class=\"name\">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $data, $matches);

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "baekhyun8100";
$databaseName = "student_information";
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
$query = "INSERT INTO student_information";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($matchcount > 0) {    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $matchcount; $i++) {
        echo("\n" . "\n");
        #echo($matches[1][$i]);
        echo strip_tags($matches[1][$i], '<div>');

        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `student_information` (`name`) VALUES ('" . strip_tags($matches[1][$i]) . "');");
    }    
} else {
    echo('No matches');
}
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598886/how-can-i-get-td-values-using-dom-and-php

Comment: I can only use regex

Comment: I do understand that xpath and DOM Document is a better choice, however due to some constraints by using xpath or dom document it will  affect the later part of my project